# How to get the real size of a view with auto layout?

Tags: ios, uiview, autolayout

I have a view in interface builder. I set the width as 600, height as 400. Then I added some constraints to make sure it display correctly on different screen-size devices. The constraints are like: 'trailing space to superview:0, leading space to superview: 0....' Here superview is the main view of the ViewController.

When simulating the app, the view displayed well, and I printed out the size of the view. The printed results show that both the frame and the bounds are still (600, 400). I thought the width of the view would equal to my screen width. What is the problem here?

I'm running it on an iPhone6. I layout the view in interface builder. The test code is

```
println("bounds width:\(myView.bounds.width), height:\(myView.bounds.height)")
println("frame width:\(myView.frame.width), height:\(myView.frame.height)")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check the size in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`,at this time,your constraints have been applied to your view